# In flutter I wants to keep the container module stable when another module changes its behaviour

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, containers, user-experience

Below is my code where two containers used one is for uploading front image another one is for uploading back image.Whenever I uploads any one front or back image another container changes its position and comes little down. I wants to avoid that another container is changing its position and wants to remain another container on its place even if other container changes[image]

```
Card(
            elevation: 5,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    InkWell(
                        //  onTap: () => ({

                        //  }),
                        onTap: () async {
                          // List<File?>? fileSelection =
                          //     await getIt<KycManager>().selectFile(widget.flag);

                          // print('=====>File uploaded====>${fileSelection}');
                          // if (fileSelection?.isEmpty == true ||
                          //     fileSelection == null) {
                          //   Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Please select file");
                          //   return;
                          // }

                          // setState(() {
                          //   img = fileSelection[0];
                          //   imgpath = '${img?.path}'; //error
                          // });
                          // ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                          //     behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
                          //     content: Text(
                          //       fileSelection != null
                          //           ? "Uploaded images ${fileSelection.first}"
                          //           : "",
                          //       style: TextStyle(
                          //           color: fileSelection != null
                          //               ? Colors.green
                          //               : Colors.red),
                          //     )));
                          // widget.onFileSelection(fileSelection);
                          FilePickerResult? fileResult = (await FilePicker
                              .platform
                              .pickFiles(allowMultiple: false));
                          String? path = fileResult != null
                              ? fileResult.files.isNotEmpty
                                  ? fileResult.files[0].path
                                  : ""
                              : "";
                          final File selectFront = File(path as String);
                          // print(selectFront.readAsBytesSync());

                          setState(() {
                            this.frontImage = selectFront;
                            this.img1 = path.toString();
                          });
                          print("front img........$path");
                        },
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                  left: w1p * 6,
                                  right: w1p * 6,
                                  top: h1p * 1),
                              child: Container(
                                  height: h1p * 6,
                                  width: w10p * 4,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                                    color: Colours.disabledText,
                                  ),
                                  child: Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                          horizontal: w1p * 2,
                                          vertical: h1p * 2),
                                      child: Row(children: [
                                        InkWell(
                                          onTap: () async {
                                            // File? file = File("");
                                            // String filePath = "";
                                            XFile? fileResult =
                                                await ImagePicker()
                                                    .pickImage(
                                                        source: ImageSource
                                                            .camera);
                                            String? path = fileResult !=
                                                    null
                                                ? fileResult.path.isNotEmpty
                                                    ? fileResult.path
                                                    : ""
                                                : "";

                                            final File selectFront =
                                                File(path as String);
                                            setState(() {
                                              this.frontImage = selectFront;
                                              this.img1 = path.toString();
                                            });
                                          },
                                          child: Container(
                                            child: Center(
                                              child: SvgPicture.asset(
                                                  "assets/images/kycImages/camera.svg",
                                                  height: h1p * 4),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Text(
                                          'Upload Front Image',
                                          style: TextStyles.textStyle121,
                                        ),
                                      ]))),
                            ),
                            this.frontImage != null
                                ? showImage(img1)
                                : SizedBox()
                          ],
                        )),
                    InkWell(
                        onTap: () async {
                          FilePickerResult? fileResult = (await FilePicker
                              .platform
                              .pickFiles(allowMultiple: false));
                          String? path = fileResult != null
                              ? fileResult.files.isNotEmpty
                                  ? fileResult.files[0].path
                                  : ""
                              : "";
                          final File selectBack = File(path as String);
                          setState(() {
                            this.backImage = selectBack;
                            this.img2 = path.toString();
                          });
                        },
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: w1p * 2, right: w1p * 3, top: h1p * 1),
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                height: h1p * 6,
                                width: w10p * 4,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                                  color: Colours.disabledText,
                                ),
                                child: Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                        horizontal: w1p * 2,
                                        vertical: h1p * 2),
                                    child: Row(children: [
                                      InkWell(
                                        onTap: () async {
                                          XFile? fileResult =
                                              await ImagePicker().pickImage(
                                                  source:
                                                      ImageSource.camera);
                                          String? path = fileResult != null
                                              ? fileResult.path.isNotEmpty
                                                  ? fileResult.path
                                                  : ""
                                              : "";
                                          final File selectBack =
                                              File(path as String);
                                          setState(() {
                                            this.backImage = selectBack;
                                            this.img2 = path.toString();
                                          });
                                        },
                                        child: Container(
                                          child: SvgPicture.asset(
                                            "assets/images/kycImages/camera.svg",
                                            height: h1p * 4,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      // ),
                                      Text(
                                        'Upload Back Image',
                                        style: TextStyles.textStyle121,
                                      ),
                                    ])),
                              ),
                              this.backImage != null
                                  ? showImage(img2)
                                  : SizedBox()
                            ],
                          ),
                        )),
                  ],
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: w1p * 3,
                    right: w1p * 6,
                  ),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: maxWidth,
                    height: 50,
                    child: ListView.separated(
                      separatorBuilder: (context, index) => SizedBox(
                        width: 220,
                      ),
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      itemCount: imgfiles.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        String doc = imgfiles[index];
                        print('the whole filepath  >>>>>>>>$doc');

                        List doc1 = doc.split("?");
                        List doc2 = doc1[0].split(".");
                        List fpath = doc2;
                        print('doc1.>>>>>>>>$doc1');

                        print('fpath.>>>>>>>>$fpath');
                        final fp = doc2.last;
                        String filepath = fp.toString();
                        print('filepath.>>>>>>>>$filepath');

                        Future<File?> downloadFile(
                            String url, String name) async {
                          final appStorage =
                              await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
                          final file = File('${appStorage.path}/$name');
                          try {
                            final response = await Dio().get(url,
                                options: Options(
                                    responseType: ResponseType.bytes,
                                    followRedirects: false,
                                    receiveTimeout: 0));
                            final raf = file.openSync(mode: FileMode.write);
                            raf.writeFromSync(response.data);
                            await raf.close();
                            return file;
                          } catch (e) {
                            return null;
                          }
                        }

                        Future openFile(
                            {required String url, String? filename}) async {
                          final file = await downloadFile(url, filename!);
                          if (file == null) return;
                          print(
                              'path for pdf file++++++++++++ ${file.path}');
                          OpenFile.open(file.path);
                        }

                        // filepath != 'pdf'
                        //     ?
                        if (filepath != 'pdf') {
                          print('object++++====');
                          return GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                showDialog(
                                    context: context,
                                    builder: (context) {
                                      return Dialog(
                                        child: SizedBox(
                                          width: maxWidth * 5,
                                          height: maxHeight * 0.5,
                                          child: Image.network(
                                            // ignore: unnecessary_string_interpolations
                                            '$doc',
                                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    });
                              },
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                    left: w1p * 6, right: w1p * 6),
                                child: imageDialog(doc),
                              ));
                        } else {
                          return GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                openFile(
                                    url: doc, filename: 'adhaarcard.pdf');
                              },
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                  left: w1p * 6,
                                  // right: w1p * 6,
                                ),
                                child: imageDialog(doc),
                              ));
                        }
                      },
                    ),

                    //_checkController();
                  ),
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: w1p * 6,
                          right: w1p * 6,
                          top: h1p * 2,
                          bottom: h1p),
                      child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                        child: TextButton(
                          onPressed: () async {
                            print(
                                "aadharfront--${frontImage} backImg --- ${backImage}");
                            Map<String, dynamic> aadhaar =
                                await getIt<KycManager>().adhaarDetails(
                                    companyId, frontImage!, backImage!);
                            setState(() {
                              this.onPressed == 1;
                            });
                            String adharmsg = aadhaar.toString();
                            String adhaarmsg = adharmsg.substring(4);

                            Fluttertoast.showToast(
                                msg: adhaarmsg,
                                toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
                                gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
                                timeInSecForIosWeb: 3,
                                backgroundColor:
                                    Color.fromARGB(255, 253, 153, 33),
                                textColor: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 12.0);
                          },
                          child: Text(
                            'CAPTURED',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                          ),
                          style: ButtonStyle(
                              backgroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(
                                Color.fromARGB(255, 253, 153, 33),
                              ),
                              shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<
                                      RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                                  RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                                side: BorderSide(
                                  width: 1,
                                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 150, 146, 146),
                                ),
                              ))),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: maxWidth * 0.1,
                    ),
                    onPressed == 1
                        ? Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                left: w1p * 0.03,
                                right: w1p * 1,
                                top: h1p * 1),
                            child: adhaarDetails(),
                          )
                        : const SizedBox()
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is happening because you didn't use any constraints.

1st approach you can try.

- Align Row Items By using mainAxisAlignment.start

2nd approach can be

- Give constraint to The Row (use this approach if above approach not works)

Comment: what constraint should I give to the Row 1st approach is not working

Comment: like a fixed height should work